# Is it possible to use any kind of database in Flutter Desktop

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-desktop

After 2 weeks of UI code for my desktop app I just found out that firebase doesn't support flutter desktop, Sqflite doesn't work too. So I how can I access any kind of database for flutter desktop?
I've already tried Sqflite and Firebase, and Rest API isn't enough.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Found anything yet? I just wasted couple weeks too on all the hardest parts of my desktop app only to realise I cant use real time database :(

Comment: Nah, switched back to electron

Comment: Hi, for anyone who is interested in this topic. please upvote for the feature request in the link below. thanx!

https://firebase.uservoice.com/forums/948424-general/suggestions/46591750-desktop-windows-linux-macos-support-for-flutte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [page](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Desktop-shells):

> The Flutter desktop APIs are still in early stages of development, and are **subject to change without warning**. No backwards compatibility, either API or ABI, will be provided. Expect any code using these libraries to need to be updated and recompiled after any Flutter update
>
> Writing plugins is supported on all platforms, however there are currently very few plugins that actually have desktop support.

You can find some plugins that can be used on desktop on the following link:

https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding/tree/master/plugins

Currently there is no plugin for firebase on flutter desktop or any other database.

Flutter desktop is still in early stages so it's probably better not to use it for production.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, the [Supabase](https://pub.dev/packages/supabase) Works perfectly on Desktop and all other platforms.

Also, for a local Database [Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) a Works.

Comment: Is Window 7 supported?

Comment: Hive is deprecated. dont use it.