# Does Flutter + Cloud Firestore working in Desktop App?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-desktop

Since I’m using the Cloud Firestore Database service, I am using cloud_firestore, the plugin for the Cloud Firestore API.
Does it work for Desktop app?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57444938/10409567

Comment: is this answer still true today?