# Flutter Desktop: Firebase Auth could not find a valid GoogleService-Info.plist

Tags: swift, flutter, dart

I have created a **desktop** flutter project. I added in the **pubspec.yaml** library:

firebase_auth: ^ 0.15.5 + 2

read more: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire

I opened the **Xcode** to insert **Google-Services.plist** in the **runner** folder. When I run the project I get this error, I don't know what procedure I'm doing wrong. I appreciate any help, thanks.

Before publishing this post, I have been informed here but cannot find the solution.
[Could not find a valid GoogleService-Info.plist in your project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45317777/could-not-find-a-valid-googleservice-info-plist-in-your-project)

```
Launching lib/main.dart on macOS in debug mode...
Building macOS application...                                                  
2020-03-18 16:08:06.178 elahorcadocanariowebpanel[39295:504644] Configuring the default Firebase app...
2020-03-18 16:08:06.186 elahorcadocanariowebpanel[39295:504644] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.firebase.core', reason: '`[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) could not find a valid GoogleService-Info.plist in your project. Please download one from https://console.firebase.google.com/.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3a4048ab __exceptionPreprocess + 250
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff706be805 objc_exception_throw + 48
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3a404701 +[NSException raise:format:] + 189
        3   elahorcadocanariowebpanel           0x0000000101fd152a +[FIRApp configure] + 138
        4   elahorcadocanariowebpanel           0x0000000101ff6fa6 -[FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin init] + 214
        5   elahorcadocanariowebpanel           0x0000000101ff6d83 +[FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin registerWithRegistrar:] + 195
        6   elahorcadocanariowebpanel           0x0000000101f8cc3c $s25elahorcadocanariowebpanel24RegisterGeneratedPlugins8registryySo21FlutterPluginRegistry_p_tF + 188
        7   elahorcadocanariowebpanel           0x0000000101f8c49c $s25elahorcadocanariowebpanel17MainFlutterWindowC12awakeFromNibyyF + 492
        8   elahorcadocanariowebpanel           0x0000000101f8c62b $s25elahorcadocanariowebpanel17MainFlutterWindowC12awakeFromNibyyFTo + 43
        9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3a37c965 -[NSSet makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 231
        10  AppKit                              0x00007fff3752a2f0 -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:] + 1485
        11  AppKit                              0x00007fff3751e156 loadNib + 401
        12  AppKit                              0x00007fff3751d719 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:options:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 693
        13  AppKit                              0x00007fff3751d36f -[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects:] + 201
        14  AppKit                              0x00007fff3751d148 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 446
        15  AppKit                              0x00007fff3750f355 NSApplicationMain + 505
        16  elahorcadocanariowebpanel           0x0000000101f8cb6d main + 13
        17  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff71a2c7fd start + 1
        18  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
Error waiting for a debug connection: The log reader stopped
unexpectedly.
Error launching application on macOS.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved I was adding it to the iOS folder instead of the MacOS folder.

Remember to allow incoming and outgoing connections in the xcode.
Otherwise it will not work for them.

They must put the file inside the resource folder.


[image]

Comment: Hi, did you used same GoogleService-Info.plist as for iOS application? Because I cannot see on firebase that you can create a project for macos dekstop app? @DomingoMG

Comment: Yes, the same file